# Fragment view in ViewPager is not restored when resuming

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tabs

I have ActionBar Tabs setup. It consists of 4 tabs. Everything is fine until I navigate away from `TabbedFragment` and returning back.

I create tabs like this:

```
  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        final ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        tabs = Lists.newArrayList();
        tabs.add(new TabDefinition<>("Tab 1"));
        tabs.add(new TabDefinition<>("Tab 2"));
        tabs.add(new TabDefinition<>("Tab 3"));
        tabs.add(new TabDefinition<>("Tab 4"));


        for (TabDefinition tab : tabs) {
            actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(tab.text)
                .setTag(tab.tag)
                .setTabListener(this));
        }
    }
```

And initialize adapter like this:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.paging_tab_container, container, false);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.pager);

    viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) {

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            return tabs.get(position).fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return tabs.size();
        }
    });

    viewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            getActionBar().setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
        }
    });

    viewPager.setCurrentItem(getActionBar().getSelectedNavigationIndex(), true);
}
```

When returning back to `TabbedFragment` selected tab and 1 next to it would not have any content. Just empty view. But if I select current + 2 fragment content is loaded. And then returning to that first fragment content is reloaded.
For example I have A, B, C, D tabs. Before leaving `TabbedFragment` I had selected tab A.
When returning to `TabbedFragment` I still am at tab A, but it's empty. So is tab B.
But when selecting tab C it is created and loaded. Returning to tab A it is recreated.

What could be the problem here?

Comment: You have View Pager inside fragment, now what is the use of tabs ? Can you provide the actual structure ?

Comment: This is all there is. What else do you need?

Comment: Okay, so real quick question. You have a viewpager inside a fragment inside an activity with a viewpager ?

Comment: Yep, Activity has a Fragment with ViewPager, which displays fragments.

Comment: How did you solve it?

Comment: Had to extend adapter and force destruction of fragments and avoid storing their state.

Answer (score 90, accepted):

After a while ran into the same problem again, so updating this question.
If you're using `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` you should provide `FragmentManager` via `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()`. See [Issue 55068: ViewPager doesn't refresh child fragments when back navigation via backstack](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=55068)

Comment: How does this work for the support v4 FragmentManager?

Comment: How to set ViewPager to first page while coming back from another fragment?

Answer (score 4):

Okay so When using a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` your fragments will be destroyed when you navigate anymore than one fragment Away since by default `offScreenPageLimit` is set to 1 by default just as mentioned above.

Typically this Class is used for an activity that has a very large set of `Fragments`, i.e have to scroll through a large amount of views. If your application does not need more than say 3-4 tabs I would suggest using `FragmentPagerAdapter` instead, and then specifying your offScreenPageLimit to something like 3, so if you get to the 4th Tab, all 3 tabs before will still be in memory.

Here is some Sample Code for a project on github that i created illustrating how to dynamically load the fragments if you don't want to add this offScreenPageLimit.

https://github.com/lt-tibs1984/InterfaceDemo/blob/master/src/com/divshark/interfacedemo/InterfaceDemoMain.java

Walk through all this code in this Class, and you will see how I'm dynamically loading the fragments, each time my `ViewPager` is slid over. Most notably at the bottom.

You can download this code, and use it as a test base for what you want to do. 
Try adding the setOffScreenPageLimit(2) in the onCreate() method for the viewPager and notice the different behavior. To check the behavior, edit the text in fragment 1. Navigate Away and navigate back, with this set or not. You will see when it is set, the fragment's text remains what you change it to, since the fragment is never recreated.

Please provide additional questions if you have them.

GoodLuck

**UPDATE**

```
private static final String [] fragmentClasses = {"com.example.project.YourFragment1","com.example.project.YourFragment2","com.example.project.YourFragment3"};



 viewPager.setAdapter(new FragmentStatePagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) {

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

       Fragment fragmentAtPosition = null;

       // $$$$ This is the Important Part $$$$$
       // Check to make sure that your array is not null, size is greater than 0 , current position is greater than equal to 0, and position is less than length
       if((fragmentClasses != null) && (fragmentClasses.length > 0)&&(position >= 0)&& (position < fragmentClasses.length))
        {
       // Instantiate the Fragment at the current position of the Adapter
        fragmentAtPosition = Fragment.instantiate(getBaseContext(), fragmentClasses[position]);
        fragmentAtPosition.setRetainInstance(true);

       }

        return fragmentAtPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return fragmentClasses.length;
    }
});
```

Comment: Well, your sample code is the same as mine. Only difference is the adapter. If I use `FragmentPagerAdapter` in some cases it don't even load Fragment content on the first time.

Answer (score 2):

The problem exists in the Fragments you use as tabs, I think. They seem to not show anything when they are resumed (see [Fragment lifecycle](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html#Creating)). The "weird" issue that only the currently selected +/-1 tab is empty, is because the [`offScreenPageLimit`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html#setOffscreenPageLimit%28int%29) of your `ViewPager` is 1 by default. All tabs above this threshold are re-created.

Therefore, increasing the value will -- in your case -- cause all your tabs to appear empty after resuming. Check in your Fragment code which lifecycle methods you use to inflate your layout, set adapters and so forth, because that's what's causing your trouble.

Comment: Yeah, increasing `offScreenPageLimit` made all tabs empty. I played around and it looks like they are not added to `ViewPager` at all when resumed. All I can see is empty `ViewPager` - fragments have different background then `ViewPager` for easier debugging.

Comment: And it does not depend on `Fragment` none of the fragment lyfecycle methods were called when resuming those fragments. Tried few different implementations...

Comment: I dont think increasing value will do the job, as offScreenPageLimit loads number of +/- pages of ViewPager.

Comment: Yes, I didn't mean that increasing the value would _solve_ the issue --- it just explains why only the current +/- 1 tabs were empty.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this happens because while loading fragment android loads current and current+1, if you debug you would not see onPause getting called for the immediate next fragment.

You can reload content programmatically in onTabChanged() method of TabHost.OnTabChangeListener.

Comment: I'm not using TabHost. I'm using ActionBar tabs.

Comment: Ok. Then have you tried reloading in onTabSelected() method?

Comment: I have also figured out the problem was two fragments loading but current fragment is empty. even now found not solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

After doing much research, this worked for me.
I have a complex layout with 3 tabs in a fragment, that gets switched out for other fragments. I realized that the `ViewpagerAdapter` will retain state, even if you press the home button. My problem was switching back and forth would null out the child fragment UI view elements and crash. The key is to not `new` out your `ViewPagerAdapter`. Adding the null check for the Adapter worked for me. Also, be sure to allocate `setOffscreenPageLimit()` for your needs. Also, from what I understand `setRetainInstance(true);` should not be used for fragments that have UI, it is designed for headless fragments.

In the fragment that holds your Tabs:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tab, container, false);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tablayout);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewPager);

    //Important!!! Do not fire the existing adapter!!
    if (viewPagerAdapter == null) {
        viewPagerAdapter = new ViewPagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new AFragment(), "A");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new BFragment(), "B");
        viewPagerAdapter.addFragments(new CFragment(), "C");
    }
    //Allocate retention buffers for three tabs, mandatory
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setAdapter(viewPagerAdapter);

    return view;
}
```

Comment: Is this safe? I mean, it does not bring memory leaks?

Answer (score 0):

Or more simply when navigating back to `tabbedfragment` (assuming you use an intent and the fragment is within an activity) use:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
```

This keeps the original activity and moves it to the top of the stack rather than recreating it, thus you never need to recreate the viewPager.