# fragment getItem() method in viewpager is not called when coming back

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

Hi there I am using viewpager to display three tabs inside a fragment in my app.While loading for first time it works correctly but when come back from next fragment getitem() method is not called and my previous data is lost.please assist me.

Here is my viewpager implementation

```
import com.devpoint.rprtjobs.R;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTabHost;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;


public class MainActivity extends Fragment {

   // Declaring Your View and Variables

   Toolbar toolbar;
   ViewPager pager;
   SwipeViewPagerAdapter adapter;
   SlidingTabLayout tabs;
   CharSequence Titles[]={"OnGoing","UpComing","Expired"};
   int Numboftabs =3;
private View rootView;

   @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        try {
            rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main,
                    container, false);


       adapter =  new SwipeViewPagerAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(),Titles,Numboftabs);

       // Assigning ViewPager View and setting the adapter
       pager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pager);
       pager.setAdapter(adapter);

       // Assiging the Sliding Tab Layout View
       tabs = (SlidingTabLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
       tabs.setDistributeEvenly(true); // To make the Tabs Fixed set this true, This makes the tabs Space Evenly in Available width

       // Setting Custom Color for the Scroll bar indicator of the Tab View
       tabs.setCustomTabColorizer(new SlidingTabLayout.TabColorizer() {
           @Override
           public int getIndicatorColor(int position) {
               return getResources().getColor(R.color.tabsScrollColor);
           }
       });

       // Setting the ViewPager For the SlidingTabsLayout
       tabs.setViewPager(pager);

       pager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);

       pager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {
            public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {}
            public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {}

            public void onPageSelected(int position) {

                if(position ==0)
                {
                    SwipeViewPagerAdapter.Pagename = "ListOnGoing";
                }
                else if(position ==1) 
                {
                    SwipeViewPagerAdapter.Pagename = "ListUpComing"; 
                }
                else if(position ==2)
                {
                    SwipeViewPagerAdapter.Pagename = "ListExpired";
                }

                }
        });


   }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return rootView;

   }

}
```

Here is my addapter

package com.devpoint.tabsswipe;

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by Edwin on 15/02/2015.
 */
public class SwipeViewPagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {

    CharSequence Titles[]; // This will Store the Titles of the Tabs which are Going to be passed when ViewPagerAdapter is created
    int NumbOfTabs; // Store the number of tabs, this will also be passed when the ViewPagerAdapter is created
    public static String Pagename="ListOnGoing";


    // Build a Constructor and assign the passed Values to appropriate values in the class
    public SwipeViewPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,CharSequence mTitles[], int mNumbOfTabsumb) {
        super(fm);

        this.Titles = mTitles;
        this.NumbOfTabs = mNumbOfTabsumb;

    }

    //This method return the fragment for the every position in the View Pager
    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            //Pagename = "ListOnGoing";
            ListOnGoing mListOnGoing = new ListOnGoing();  
            return mListOnGoing;
        case 1:
            //Pagename = "ListUpComing";
            ListUpComing mListUpComing = new ListUpComing(); 
            return mListUpComing;
        case 2:
            //Pagename = "ListExpired";
            ListExpaire mListExpaire = new ListExpaire();
            return mListExpaire;
        default:
            return null;
    }

    }

    // This method return the titles for the Tabs in the Tab Strip

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return Titles[position];
    }

    // This method return the Number of tabs for the tabs Strip

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return NumbOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Comment: You may want to check this SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932541/fragment-view-in-viewpager-is-not-restored-when-resuming

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fragment view in ViewPager is not restored when resuming](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932541/fragment-view-in-viewpager-is-not-restored-when-resuming)

Answer (score 0):

```
boolean isResumedFragment = false;

//in OncreateView Check this

if(rootView!=null){

 isResumedFragment = true;

}

if(isResumedFragment){

//remove all added fragment

getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(FRAGMENTINSTANCE)
                    .commitAllowingStateLoss();

}

//after that set adapter in view pager and call 

adapter.notifydatasetchanged();
```