# How to work with swipable tabs with bottom navigation

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-bottomnav

[image]

Hi, I have been trying to use swipe tab with bottom navigation bar, but on re-selection of tab swipe lacks and nothing shows. I am calling fragments of swipe tabs from bottom bar fragment. This is my code

```
    public class WalletFragment extends Fragment {
    private ViewPager viewPager;
    private WalletTabsAdapter mAdapter;
    PagerSlidingTabStrip wallettabs;
    // Tab titles

    public static WalletFragment newInstance(int instance) {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt("input", instance);
        WalletFragment fragment = new WalletFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_wallet, container, false);
        // Initilization
        viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.walletpager);
        wallettabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wallettabs);
        mAdapter = new WalletTabsAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        wallettabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
        /**
         * on swiping the viewpager make respective tab selected
         * */
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Comment: is that an advisable approach to have both tabs and bottom navigation view? as per  [Material Guidelines](https://material.io/design/components/bottom-navigation.html#usage)

Comment: It just says to use it with caution

Comment: Take for example the Inbox tab in the Youtube App

Answer (score 4):

Use `getChildFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` . See [viewpager didnt show anything after change bottom navigation menu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21932541/fragment-view-in-viewpager-is-not-restored-when-resuming)
. I've tried it and it work perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
viewPager = (ViewPager) rootView.findViewById(R.id.walletpager);
    wallettabs = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) rootView.findViewById(R.id.wallettabs);
    mAdapter = new WalletTabsAdapter(getFragmentManager());
    viewPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    wallettabs.setViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2); // add this line
```

It there is parent view pager for bottom navigation then you can also use this

```
parrentViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);
```

Comment: @VishalArora, Can you try with this https://github.com/ncapdevi/FragNav ?I think it may help

Comment: I am using this Fragnav code and it works fine, but issue is when i try to re-call tabs fragment from Fragnav fragment it stops working. Just want to tell you, i am not using fragment activity.

Comment: @VishalArora, can you try to debug the stack of the current tab  which is you selected from FragNav?

Comment: I have enabled debugging on current tab and this is the result.    No adapter attached; skipping layout         mName=null mIndex=-1 mCommitted=false

Answer (score 0):

I had that problem too. My problem was that I had two `ViewPager`s in two different tabs of BottomNavigation and they both contained ViewPager in layout:

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```

After I change the ID of one of them to differentiate, it worked!

```
 <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container2" <!-- Changed ID -->
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />
```